# Null or Not Null value in mysql where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am writing small mysql select query in php code and in the select query it has three different where condition like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE pid = $pid AND qid = $qid AND text="$text" ;
```

Dynamically it will change the variable , some times one of the variable  will become null at that time my condition would look like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE pid = $pid AND text="$text" ;
```

Same thing can be for text and pid also ,How can I do that , Is there any solutions or should I have to go for if/switch condition in php ..

Comment: Use an `if`/`switch` in php.

Comment: See @GordonLinoff answer, note that your code is open for SQL injections have a look at prepared statements.

Comment: It's bad idea, because, in case when all your parameters will be null you will receive terrible query that will select all records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if`s to create a query and execute a PDO prepared statement ( http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php ).

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 = 1";
$params = array();

if(null !== $pid) {
    $query .= ' AND pid = :pid';
    $params[':pid'] = $pid;
}
if(null !== $qid ) {
    $query .= ' AND qid = :qid';
    $params[':qid'] = $qid;
}
if(null !== $text) {
    $query .= ' AND text = :text';
    $params[':text'] = $text;
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($params);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: @prabhu, glad to hear this.

Comment: Your edit makes this answer useless ... instead you could delete your answer and upvote the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here another mysql variant:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    IF($pid > 0, pid = $pid, 1 = 1)
AND IF($qid > 0, qid = $qid, 1 = 1)
AND IF($text > '', `text` = $text, 1 = 1)
;
```

But here hardcoded values. And you can't select rows where pid or qid exactly equals to 0 or text equals to '' (empty string). 

And you can receive query that will be select all rows in your table, i suppose it will be very bad...

Php:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'root');
$pid = 1;
$qid = 2;
$text = '3';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 1 = 1';
$params = [];
if (isset($pid)) {
    $sql .= ' AND pid = :pid';
    $params[':pid'] = $pid;
}
if (isset($qid)) {
    $sql .= ' AND qid = :qid';
    $params[':qid'] = $qid;
}
if (isset($text)) {
    $sql .= ' AND `text` = :text';
    $params[':text'] = $text;
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($params);
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($result);
```

Comment: The second version is **massively** better than the first, and that first thing I'm not even sure why it's there. It's bizarre and wasteful. Conditions that aren't necessary don't belong in the query string, it's the job of the application code to omit them, not MySQL to ignore them. The second version can be cleaned up by making `$conditions = []` and then appending to that array, later introducing that into the query with `implode(' AND ', $conditions)` to make this a lot more dynamic and remove the pointless `1=1` thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can include it into the SQL like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE ("$pid" = "" OR pid = "$pid") 
AND ("$qid" = "" OR qid = "$qid") 
AND ("$text" = "" OR text="$text") ;
```

The MySql-Server will see `... WHERE ("" = "" OR pid = "")` and optimize the query before executing it by removing this part.

Comment: **No**. This just doubles down on the already rampant injection problem.

Comment: Well, yes, I agree, SQL injection must be dealt with. However this is out of scope of this question. For example, $pid could have been casted to (int) beforehand, and $text might be a static string.

Comment: It's these assumptions that everything's okay that causes massive problems. Writing correct code is never out of scope. Also `==` is not a valid MySQL comparison.